# Can I create a UWP project in .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, uwp

I have Universal Windows Platform project with .NET Core I think. I want to convert it to target .NET Framework.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything , as such your question is very vague...

Comment: Although UWP is based on .NET Core, it is actually build on morden Windows API so lot's of its functions cannot be used by .net framework. Like the answer has clarified by mm8. So instead of thinking about convert it to target .net framework, try to think about build .NET standard library so that you can use common code in different platforms would be a better idea on top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed build a UWP app using .NET and C#, but UWP apps includes only a subset of the types provided in the full .NET Framework for each namespace. A main difference between a UWP app and a .NET desktop application is that the former runs in a sandbox that is isolated from other processes, whereas a traditional desktop application typically runs as a full-trust process.

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/missing-dot-net-apis-in-unity-and-uwp) for more information about the missing .NET APIs in UWP. You won't be able to use these in a UWP app.