# How do I reference .NET Framework 4.6 class library from Universal Windows project?

Tags: .net, .net-core, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I cannot do it, because Universal Windows project targets .Net Core and it is not a supported scenario according to Visual Studio 2019.

**Note:** Please do not write answers like "Why do you want to do that?", "Convert the library to .net standard.", "It is deprecated.".

I'm looking for **ANY** possible solution including hacks, not recommended techniques, using older Universal Windows versions, etc..

Comment: there is no hack as  .net core runtime can not load .net framework lib which is bound to old mscorlib.dll, so you have to port your dll into standard version then only it can be loaded by  .net core 3 runtime

Comment: UWP targets .NET Core. If you need symbols from .NET Framework you might be able to find substitutions for them in .NET Core. Unless you provide more information for your use case, the question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You need to convert the library to .NET Standard, or some other TFM that UWP *can* reference. I realise that you said not to write answers like this, but: ***it is still the answer to the question***.  Rejecting reality will not change this.

Comment: So there is really no workaround? I tried creating a pcl library v4.6 Profile44 and reference the .net framework class library from this pcl library and reference the pcl library from the uwp project. But I got an error "Reference to type 'FileInfo' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found.". There must be a way how to do it. My other idea is to compile uwp project as .net framework app, not .net core app, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: As this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114854/can-i-create-uwp-project-in-net-framework-how) mentioned, lot's of UWP functions cannot be used by .net framework, you still need to think about converting the library to .NET Standard that UWP can reference instead of compiling uwp project as .net framework app.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is by using **brokered component**. We had the same issue on my work. We want to have a tablet/touch friendly UI on Windows 10 but we also have legacy DLLs that are built on .NET Framework. The only catch is that you won't be able to deploy the app in the Windows store because, first, it won't be approved, second, you'll have to install the .NET Framework DLLs to the file system which the store can't do because it's sand-boxed.

If you're gonna go this path, you'll have to think of a deployment strategy other than the Windows store.

Would I recommend this approach? No.

Is this a long term solution? I don't think so. The steps to make it work is very tedious and you have to figure out a way on how to make it work on later version of Visual Studio since the samples from the documentation is using Visual Studio 2015 and 2017. Right now I use VS 2019 to build it, but the source I have is migrated from 2015 to 2017 and now to 2019. There's a template downloadable for 2015 and 2017 but none for 2019 and 2022.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps